# Assign value to a variable in a return query in PL/PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a Postgres function where I am trying to get recommended friends for a user-

```
create function get_recommended_friends(id VARCHAR)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        friend_id VARCHAR,
    is_friend_recommendable BOOLEAN
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    user user%rowtype;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO user from user where id = id;

    isFriendNearTheUser BOOLEAN;

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            friend_id,
            is_friend_recommendable(player, subject.*, isFriendNearTheUser) AS is_friend_recommendable,
        FROM friend friend
        WHERE friend_id != id
          isFriendNearTheUser := ST_DWithin(user.current_point, friend.current_point, user.maximum_wanted_distance)
          ....
      .....
      AND ....
          AND...
END
$$;
```

obviously this code doesn't run right now because I am trying to assign the value in the where clause
`isFriendNearTheUser := ST_DWithin(user.current_point, friend.current_point, user.maximum_wanted_distance)`

I'd like to calculate it once and then pass it in the `is_friend_recommendable` function so i don't have to calcualte it everytime in that function.

Is this possible to do that in this query? Will i need to re-write the query in another way?

If i keep calculating the distance, I am seeing slowness in my query. My motivation is to calculate it once and then pass it.

Comment: 1) Don't use `user` it is [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) 2) `isFriendNearTheUser BOOLEAN;` needs to be in the `DECLARE` section. 3) You need to further describe what this: *...is_friend_recommendable function so i don't have to calcualte it everytime in that function.* means?

Comment: It would seem that you cannot avoid the process of *calculate it every time* because the value of `friend.current_point` changes for each row thus the result of the calculation changes for every row.